# How to declare 2 function in a module

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Hi i have a module require.js :

```
define([], function() {

    return {
        test:function (value,element,params )
    {
        if (value.length == 0 && params.mandatory === "True")
            return false;

        return true;
    }

}
});
```

I need to add a second function "test2" in this module, how can i do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, you're returning an object literal, so add another property to it:

```
define([], function() {

    return {
        test:function (value,element,params )
        {
            if (value.length == 0 && params.mandatory === "True")
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        },//<-- comma to separate properties, much like {foo:'bar', val: 1234}
        test2: function()
        {//here's test2 definition
        }
    };
});
```

That said, the callback, passed to define, allows you to *take your time* as it were:

```
define([], function()
{
    var mod = {};
    mod.test = function(value, element, params)
    {
        return !(value.length == 0 && params.mandatory === "True");//does the same as your code
    };
    mod.test2 = function()
    {
        var value = 'foobar', params = {mandatory: true};//instead of checking True, pass bool if possible?
        return mod.test(value, null, params);//instead of this: much safer!
    };
    return mod;//return object here
}
```

Comment: @ user1428798: Note the comma (`,`) between the two properties.

Comment: yes , i miss the comma :)